# Does a Django Model Serializer need performance tuning?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is a Django serializer doing things like .only() on the same fields that are specified in the Serializer Meta: fields attribute or do I have to do it manually like saying in my view:

```
def get_queryset(self)
   return SomeModel.objects.only('my_field_on_serializer')
```

?

Comment: Yep you need to do it separately from the serializer

Comment: I see... sad to hear. Anyway, thanks for answering :D

Comment: Just a small update. After using only on the 11 fields out of 25 that i needed the response time went down 15%